# Silent Installation for msi using Install shiled

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, custom-action, silent

I have an msi project created using installshield. This works good when installed using GUI window. But when I am going through silent installation, I am getting an error with a CustomAction that I have created, which will simply generate a log file. Since it is working correctly during GUI installation I feel pretty sure, the CustomAction is not an issue.
Command I have used for silent installation

**msiexec /i "Setup.msi" /qn /l*v C:\msilog.txt**

Is there something that I must do to suppress the next buttons in the GUI mode during silent installation?

Comment: I didn't have experience with installshield, but had some with WiX toolset. There two different type of sequences, one for GUI mode [InstallUISequence](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/installuisequence.html) and one for CLI mode [InstallExecuteSequence](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/installexecutesequence.html) it might be you've set only GUI one and your installation through CLI requires some additional data or action to do. Additional [MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installexecutesequence-table) on topic.

Comment: Provide some more information about your installation configuration file, especially about how you attach your custom action into installation sequence.

Comment: Where are you scheduling your custom actions in the InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence? (InstallUISequence isn't run during a /qn silent install)

Comment: It looks like you're already generating a log file. In the log file search for "return value 3". Post 10-20 lines above where you're seeing this in the log. That will be most helpful for people to diagnose.